# Is there a faster way to calculate this?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

- Let's say I wanted to add $4$ *percent* of $225$ to $225$ . I would get $234$.
- And then I wanted to add $4$ *percent* of $234$ to $234$. And so on and so on.
- Now let's say I wanted to do this $12$ times. Is there a faster way to do this other than iterating the whole procedure $12$ times ?.
- Would $225\left(\, 1.04\,\right)^{12}$ provide the right answer ?.

Any help would ve greatly appreciated.

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: Yes.  225 (1.04)^{12} is how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $225(1.04)^{12}$ provides the right answer.  I'm not sure it is faster for this problem depending on how you compute $1.04^{12}$, but the understanding of why it works is valuable for future problems.

Comment: Thanks guys I really appreciate all of your help :)